# Curves over number fields with everywhere good reduction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

My question is the following:$\newcommand{\Q}{\Bbb Q}
\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z}$

> What is known about number fields $K$ fulfilling the condition
> $C_{g,K}$  "there is a smooth projective curve of genus $g$ over $K$, having everywhere good reduction"
> for some $g \geq 1$ ?

By the work of Fontaine and Abrashkin, it is known that for every $g>0$, the field $K = \Q$ does not satisfy $C_{g,\Q}$.
Notice that the condition $C_{g,K}$ (for some $g>0$) implies, by the functorial properties of the Jacobian, the property
$A_K$ "there is a non-zero abelian variety over $K$ having good reduction everywhere".
(Using the theory of Néron models, it should be equivalent to state that there is no non-trivial abelian scheme over the ring of integers $O_K$ (see [here](https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2016/04/29/around-abelian-schemes-over-the-integers/), where it is also explained that a CM abelian variety has potentially "good reduction everywhere")).

Thus a closely related question is:

> Do we expect the existence of (quadratic?) number fields $K \neq \Q$ such that the assertion $A_K$ does not hold (so that in particular, there is no smooth projective curve of genus $>0$ over $K$ with everywhere good reduction)?
>
> For instance, what happens if $K = \Bbb Q\left(\sqrt{-2}\right)$ or $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$?

It is mentioned [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.4648.pdf) that there is no elliptic curve over $\Q(\sqrt 2)$ with everywhere good reduction. The same happens with $\Q(i)$, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/219115). Examples of abelian surfaces with everywhere good reduction (i.e. the opposite of what I'm looking for) are mentioned [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3821v3.pdf).

By some analogy discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16602), it may be useful to note that $\Q(i)$ and $\Q(\sqrt 2)$ have no non-trivial unramified extension (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26491)).

It was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86900) whether *every* number field $K \neq \Q$ satisfies $C_{g,K}$ for some $g>0$, but the answer is only very partial.
Furtherfore, it is explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139774/) that for every $g \geq 0$, there is *some* number field $K$ such that $C_{g,K}$ holds — this is different from my question, where I want $K$ to be fixed at the beginning.

Comment: According to comments to the accepted answer in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16600/bad-reduction-for-elliptic-curves, there is an example of elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{29})$ which has good reduction everywhere. It is $E:y^2+xy+\varepsilon^2y=x^3$, where $\varepsilon=\frac{5+\sqrt{29}}{2}$.

Comment: I am aware of this (I already linked this question in my post). Moreover, for $g=2$, it is claimed [here](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/MasterSerra.pdf#page=5) that the curve $y^2=x^5-1$ has good reduction everywhere over $K = \Q(i, \sqrt[5]{2}, \sqrt{1 - \zeta_5})$.

Comment: According to [this document](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/notes/274-Schoof.pdf#page=41), Fontaine's proof also shows works «for “small” fields $K$, e.g. $\Q(\zeta_n)$ for $n \leq 7$»

Comment: See also the following papers by R. Schoof: http://mat.uniroma2.it/~schoof/zeta20.pdf, http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~schoof/sqrt6.pdf, http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~schoof/abcyc.pdf.

Comment: According to Mestre's [Formules explicites et minorations de conducteurs de variétés algébriques](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1986__58_2_209_0/), remarque 3, there are examples of curves with good reduction everywhere over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt D)$ where $D=6, 28, 29, 41$

Comment: See also the top of p. 362 in Narkiewicz's _Rational number theory in the 20th Century, from PNT to FLT_ (§6.7.8).

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219096

Comment: The links for Schoof's paper are working with https, namely https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~schoof/zeta20.pdf

Comment: See also https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.00616, arxiv.org/abs/1410.0651

Answer (score 8):

> Do we expect the existence of (quadratic?) number fields $K \neq \Q$ such that the assertion $A_K$ does not hold (so that in particular, there is no smooth projective curve of genus $>0$ over $K$ with everywhere good reduction)?

Yes, we do. Moreover, we do know that such number fields exist. Look at the original Fontaine's paper ["Il n’y a pas de vari´et´e abelienne sur $\mathbf  Z$"](https://eudml.org/doc/143270) where he proves that there are no abelian varieties with everywhere good reduction over the following number fields: $\mathbf Q, \mathbf Q(i), \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-3})$ and $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: Thank you! I shouldn't have missed this corollary in Fontaine's paper. Still my first question remains. Moreover, one could wonder about the assertion $A_K$ for $K=\Q(\sqrt 2)$ or $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$ (notice that those fields have no non-trivial unramified extension, as the four number fields given in Fontaine's result). At least, it is known that there is no elliptic curve over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ (or over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$) with everywhere good reduction.